# Turtle Graphics Program

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(void);  
char grid[6][34] = {'0'}; // empty floor
void movement(int command);
int direction = 2; // 1 for north, 2 for east, 3 for south, 4 for west. Turtle starts facing east.
void turtleMovement(int, int);
int spacesMoved; // used after F command.
int yCoord = 0; // Y position assumed 0;
int xCoord = 0; // X position assumed 0;
bool pen = 0; // assume pen is up
void initialize(void);
char command; //  U for pen up, D for pen Down, R for right turn, L for left turn, F for forward movement with spaces moved, P for array print, and Q for end.
int main(){

    initialize();
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("commands.txt");
    infile >> command;
    while(command != 'Q'){
        if(command == 'U'){
            pen = 0;
        }
        else if(command == 'D'){
            pen = 1;
        }
        if(command == 'R' || command == 'L'){
            movement(command);
        }

        if(command == 'F'){
            infile >> spacesMoved;
            turtleMovement(yCoord, xCoord);
        }
        else if(command == 'P')
            printArray();
        infile >> command;
        }
}
//=====================================================================================================================================================
//
// Function Name: intialize
//
// Pre: none
//
// Post: sets every element of the array grid to all zeroes.
// 
//======================================================================================================================================================
void initialize()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){     //
        for(int j = 0; j < 34; j++){    // Initialization of Array to all zeros.
            grid[i][j] = '0';           //
        }
    }
}
//=====================================================================================================================================================
//
// Function Name: printArray
//
// Pre: none
//
// Post: prints out the array grid to the console
// 
//======================================================================================================================================================
void printArray()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                for(int j = 0; j < 34; j++){    
                    grid[i][j];
                    cout << grid[i][j] << (j == 33 ? "\n" : ""); // if the row gets to 33 characters a new line will be made.
                }   
}
void movement(int command)
{
    if (direction == 2){ // direction is east
        if (command == 'R')
            direction = 3;// if you're facing east and you turn right you're now facing south 
        else if (command == 'L') // if you're facing east and you turn left you're now facing north.
            direction = 1;
    }
        else if (direction == 3) // direction is south
    {
        if (command == 'R') // turn right to go west
            direction = 4;
        else if (command == 'L') // turn left to go east
            direction = 2;
    }
    else if (direction == 4) // direction is west
    {
        if (command == 'R') // right for north
            direction = 1;
        else if (command == 'L') // left for south
            direction = 3;
    }
    else if (direction == 1) // direction is north
    {
        if (command == 'R') // right for east 
            direction = 2;
        else if (command == 'L') // left for west
            direction = 4;
    }
}
void turtleMovement(int y, int x){
    if(direction == 2){
        int i = y;
                for(int j = x; j < x + spacesMoved; j++){
                    if(pen == 1)
                        grid[i][j] = '1';
                    else
                        grid[i][j] = '0';
                }
            xCoord += spacesMoved - 1;   //updates the x coordinate
    }           


        else if(direction == 3){
            for(int i = y; i < y + spacesMoved; i++){
                int j = x;
                    if(pen == 1)
                        grid[i][j] = '1';
                    else
                        grid[i][j] = '0';

            }
            yCoord += spacesMoved - 1;          //updates the y coordinate
        }
        else if(direction == 4){
            int i = y;
                for(int j = x; j > x - spacesMoved; j++){
                    if(pen == 1)
                        grid[i][j] = '1';
                    else if (pen == 0)
                        grid[i][j] = '0';
                }
            xCoord -= spacesMoved - 1;         //updates the x coordinate
        }
        else if(direction == 1){
            for(int i = y; i > y- spacesMoved; i++){
                int j = x;
                    if(pen == 1)
                        grid[i][j] = '1';
                    else
                        grid[i][j] = '0';
            }
            yCoord -=spacesMoved - 1;       //updates the y coordinate
        }
}
```

I'm having extreme frustration with my program, when I try and do a 180 turn, i.e. a R R or a L L the whole program just freezes. Is it something with my logic? or a syntax? because it doesn't give me any of those errors.

Comment: When you used the debugger, what happens when the User enter's "R R"?  Don't say "freezes", describe the flow in your post.

Comment: I recommend you use the `switch` statement.  It would make your code easier to read.  I'll also accept a lookup table as well.

Comment: Please refrain from using the ancient practice of 1 and 0 for `false` and `true` with `bool` types.  The C++ language is modern and has the keywords `false` and `true` to use with `bool` types.

Comment: Also, use `char` type for character values and `unsigned int` or `int` for integral numeric types.

Comment: What is the direction when the error occurs?

Comment: Look up on how to use the modulus or `%` operator.  This will be very useful when changing directions.  For example rotate clockwise might be expressed as `direction = (direction + 1) % 4;`.  A counter clockwise rotation may be expressed as `direction = (direction + 3) % 4;`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews an error window pops up that says "program.exe" has stopped working and gives options for debugging or closing the program.

Comment: I find that hard to believe, when you are *debugging* the program (i.e. using a debugger to single step your program). (It wouldn't give you options for debugging.)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Ill change the ifs to a switch statement.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews at any time when there's a 180 change in direction the program it produces that error message then it changes almost all of the rest of the 0's in the array to 1's. It's fairly hard to explain without pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your program is annoying me and it is a little hard to read.

Try this:

```
struct Position
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

struct Direction_Vector : Position
{
  unsigned int direction;
};

const unsigned int MAX_DIRS = 4u;


void movement(char command,
              const Direction_Vector present_dir,
              Direction_Vector&       new_dir)
{
  unsigned int dir = present_dir.direction; 
  switch (command)
  {
    case 'R':  // rotate clockwise;
      dir = (dir + 1) % MAX_DIRS;
      break;
    case 'L':  // rotate counter clockwise
      dir = (dir + (MAX_DIRS - 1)) % MAX_DIRS;
      break;
    case 'M':  // Move one position in the given direction
      switch (dir)
      {
        case 0:  // Assume north, Y decreases
           new_dir.y = present_dir.y - 1;
           break;
        case 1:  // Assume east, X increases
           new_dir.x = present_dir.x + 1;
           break;
        case 2:  // Assume south, Y increases
           new_dir.y = present_dir.y - 1;
           break;
        case 3:  // Assume west, X decreases
           new_dir.x = present_dir.x - 1;
           break;
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  new_dir.direction = dir;
}
```

You may be able to optimize the movement section by using algebra and realizing a relationship between the direction and the ordinate that gets adjusted.

Also, I have not put in any boundary checking.

Sorry if I ruined your day by simplifying a lot of your posted code.

Use a debugger and step through the above code and figure out if it handles the 180 degree turns correctly.

**Edit 1: Truth Tables**
Here are the truth tables for the movement and ordinate changes

```
Direction | Delta X | Delta Y|  // "delta" means change  
----------+---------+--------+  
    0     |    0    |   -1   |  
----------+---------+--------+  
    1     |    +1   |    0   |  
----------+---------+--------+  
    2     |    0    |   +1   |  
----------+---------+--------+  
    3     |    -1   |    0   |  
----------+---------+--------+
```

Can you come up with an algebraic equation for the ordinates based on the direction?

Comment: Numeric integral constants are *signed* integers by default.  The constant is `unsigned`, so it needs an `unsigned` literal.  The `u` suffix is used to indicate that the constant is `unsigned`.  A `signed int` can go negative whereas an `unsigned int` can't.  I haven't heard of a negative quantity, so I used `unsigned`.

Comment: Is your code possible without using a struct or a vector? Obviously it would be better to use them them but the class I'm in has not learned about them yet

Comment: Yes, pass each member in the struct individually.